# Building a quiz application

Tags: android

Hi guys am building a quiz app for android. In order to do this, i made a simple app consisting of three activities. The three activities are first, second and third question respectively with their answers. In each activity i have two buttons; next and previous, each button points to the other activity via intent object. From what i have done so far, i have achieved partially what i had in mind. Now my question is this:

is it possible to build such app without making each activity one question as i have done?
Is there another way to build this kind of app?
Is it possible to put all questions and their answers in one activity like a cardlayout in java?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, definitely. There are many ways actually.

One of them, probably the easiest, would be to have an `ArrayList<String>` for questions, another `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` for the different possibles answers to questions, and then a third `ArrayList<int>` to store the index of the chosen answer by the user.

When clicking Next and Previous, instead of launching a new Activity, you can keep track of which question you're currently showing and update the TextViews for questions and RadioButtons for answers accordingly.

Comment: if i undastnd you well, the next btn would loop forward while previous btn bckward. each value of d loop holds a question n answers? wit your suggestion, do i need a database? and if you dont mind, can u help me with code snippet?